# Third call to server can not find cookies from login (using Codenameone)

Tags: java, cookies, codenameone

My app logins into a server, which sets some cookies for authentication on subsequent connections. On the next connection, in another form, the server sees the cookies. When the app goes to a third form, the server does not see the initial login cookies. I use the same connection code for the three connections to the server.

```
        Picker establishmentPicker = new Picker();
        establishmentPicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
//
        ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest() {
            //BufferedReader br;
            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
            //findDest(c)
            }
        };


        r.setUrl("https://barq-160619.appspot.com/estabappJ");
        r.setPost(true);
        r.setCookiesEnabled(true);
        r.setUseNativeCookieStore(true);
        Cookie.setAutoStored(true);
        Cookie.isAutoStored();
        System.out.println("Getting Establishments");
    InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
        Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
        r.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
    JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
        String[] places = new String[5];
        Hashtable h;
        Hashtable t;
        Hashtable h2;
        Object o;
//                Map<String, String> data = p.parseJSON(r);
        try {   
//                    Map<String, Object> h = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
            h = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            h = null;
            System.out.println("Establishment list = null");
        }
```

Is there a way to for the persisting of the cookies? Do I need to set an expiration on the initial setting of the cookies? Or am I missing something on the app side?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are experiencing [this problem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/Ri0-9geFtuw/hAZ2nGF5AAAJ) where the native cookie store and the Java side cookie stores collide in some way. I've made some suggestions for a workaround but as far as I can tell Nick didn't file an issue on this and it got lost without a final resolution.

If you can isolate a test case please [file an issue](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new).

Comment: For now, to get around the problem I reset the cookies on the second connection to the server and they are there on the third connection request.